# My app on play store says not compatible with the device....!

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

I published my application on the play store and it says not compatible.

I have tried with many devices and it says the same thing for all of them..

here are my permissions.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.harware.camera"></uses-feature>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- External storage for caching. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- My Location -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

   <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

help would be appreciated..

Comment: Might be helpful to actually include a list of devices for which you've tried but got the `not compatible` message.

Comment: Google Nexus 4
Sony Ericsson Live With Walkman
Samsung Note I
Samsung Galaxy duos

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is the camera permission, you have to set the:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

into

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

P.S : Google play doesn't show Your app on device instantly after uploading. it takes some time.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! I guess that devices that doesn't have auto focus will be able to download the app, but this feature won't work, right?

Comment: glad it helped you, ya I believe so because there some certain devices that are capable of downloading the app with no problems so logically they don't have auto focus.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play uses the elements declared in your app manifest to filter your app from devices that do not meet it's hardware and software feature requirements.

By specifying the features that your application requires, you enable Google Play to present your application only to users whose devices meet the application's feature requirements, rather than presenting it to all users.

Declared elements are informational only, meaning that the Android system itself does not check for matching feature support on the device before installing an application. However, other services (such as Google Play) or applications may check your application's declarations as part of handling or interacting with your application. For this reason, it's very important that you declare all of the features (from the list below) that your application uses.

Each time you upload an application to the Google Play Developer Console, Google Play scans the application's manifest file. It looks for elements and evaluates them in combination with other elements, in some cases, such as and elements. After establishing the application's set of required features, it stores that list internally as metadata associated with the application .apk and the application version.

When a user searches or browses for applications using the Google Play application, the service compares the features needed by each application with the features available on the user's device. If all of an application's required features are present on the device, Google Play allows the user to see the application and potentially download it. If any required feature is not supported by the device, Google Play filters the application so that it is not visible to the user and not available for download.

Because the features you declare in elements directly affect how Google Play filters your application, it's important to understand how Google Play evaluates the application's manifest and establishes the set of required features.

[Use Feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your device is compatible with the permissions requested, there is a [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)) to check on that, as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html).

```
!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS)
```

You also can download an app (not mine) that lists all the permissions your device is capable of, [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roysolberg.android.developertools)